# How to delete ImageMagick temp files programmatically?

Tags: imagemagick

I am using `ImageMagick` library to convert files in server software. Unfortunately, it creates a lot of temp files and doesn't delete them.

Can I delete (how can I) delete them programmatically by means of IM lib?

Answer (score 2):

One solution I've seen is to export ImageMagick's temporary path between tasks.

1. Call `mktemp -d`  or (`mkdtemp()` in C)
2. Export path from previous step into `MAGICK_TEMPORARY_PATH` environment variable.
3. Execute ImageMagick task.

   1. `MagickWandGenesis()` routine
   2. *... do work ...*
   3. `MagickWandTerminus()` routine
4. Remove temporary directory from step 1.

Most temp artifacts are left on the system when an exception is handled, and/or ImageMagick's shutdown routine is not called between tasks.